# Capture post request payload from web browser network traffic using automation

Tags: java, selenium, browsermob

I am not able to capture POST request payload which is sent by chrome browser for forms.

I have tried Browser mob proxy but it only captures in har file the request url, response code but not request payload.

I want to validate the request payload via java or selenium or any automation script and not via manual verification.

Any suggestion will be helpful.

Comment: Selenium does not interact with requests. You want to use pure Java or any other tool.

Comment: pure java or any language which I can trigger through script to capture the request payload is required. If you have any reference or examples please let me know.

Comment: I do not have experience but I would read articles about HTTP request via Java language. You can definitely do a lot with it. Send POST requests, read responses etc.
[link](http://www.baeldung.com/java-http-request)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

As browser mob only captures request url and response status but not payload data. I stopped using browsermob.

I used Fiddler instead which worked perfectly for me. The only problem was unlike browser mob I had to install Fiddler application in my system for which I had to approached to my superiors for permissions  for fiddler installation.